# additional geom_point with ggplot group = variable

Tags: r, ggplot2

Is it possible to include group = variable and add another point in ggplot.

For example:

```
require(MuMIn)
require(ggplot2)

data(Cement)
d <- data.frame(Cement)
dd <- melt(d,id.var = "y")
d2 <- runif(length(dd[,1]))
d2 <- data.frame(first = dd$y,
                 second = d2)

ggplot(dd, aes(x = y,y = value,group = variable)) + 
  geom_line() + 
  geom_point(data = d2,aes(x = first,y = second))
```

This leads to an error. Eventually I would like to add the points specified here onto the line plot.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Mapped aesthetics in **ggplot2** follow a sort of inheritance pattern. When you map aesthetics at the "top" level, in `ggplot()`, they are automatically passed down to all subsequent layers.

This means that `geom_point` is looking for a `variable` column in `d2`. It won't look for `y` or `value` columns, since you explicitly re-mapped the x and y aesthetics in `geom_point()`.

The solution is either to move the top level aesthetic mappings from `ggplot()` to `geom_line()`, or to *un-map* `group` in `geom_point` using `group = NULL`.

Additionally, Didzis pointed out a third solution in the comments, which is to add `inherit.aes = FALSE` to `geom_point`.

Comment: Third solution would be to add `inherit.aes=FALSE` to `geom_point()` call