# Generating stacked bar chart corresponding to percentage count of categories with overlapping dots in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, aggregate, bar-chart

I have the following data set:

```
require(ggplot2)         # To do the graphs
require(plyr)            # To join data frames in he list
require(stringr)         # To clean strings
require(reshape2)        # To melt the data
require(scales)          # To handle percentage formats
require(grid)            # To handle units

set.seed(1)
df <- data.frame(group=c("Group A", "Group A", "Group A", "Group A", "Group B","Group B","Group B", "Group B", "Group B", "Group B", "Group B", "Group C", "Group C", "Group C", "Group C", "Group C", "Group C", "Group C", "Group C"), observation=c("OBS00001", "OBS00002", "OBS00003", "OBS00004", "OBS00005", "OBS00006", "OBS00007", "OBS00008", "OBS00009", "OBS00010", "OBS00011", "OBS00012", "OBS00013", "OBS00014", "OBS00015", "OBS00016", "OBS00017", "OBS00018", "OBS00019"), 
                 important_value = sample(1:3, 19, replace=T),
                 second_value = runif(n = 19),
                 some_random_stuff = runif(n = 19),
                 other_indicator = runif(n = 19))
```

and I would like to generate the following plot:

[image: sample bar chart]

Ideally, I would like for the plot:

- Provide percentage stacked bars derived from the counts of the values in the `important_value`
- Overlay the bars with a dot that would correspond to another arbitrary value, in this case `second_value` and would be placed on the bar but with values provided on a separate y-axis

My initial code looks like that:

```
# Melt the data frame
df_mlt <- melt(data = df[,c("observation", "group","important_value")],
                    id.vars = c("observation", "group"))
# Sort for the chart
df_mlt <- df_mlt[order(df_mlt$value, df_mlt$group),]

# Get average for the population density
df_avg <- aggregate(x = df$second_value, by = list(df$group),
                         FUN = mean, na.rm = TRUE)
# Graph
ggplot(df_mlt, aes(x = group, y = value, fill = factor(value))) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", position = "fill") +
  scale_y_continuous(labels = percent_format()) +
  geom_point(data = df_avg, aes(x = as.numeric(Group.1), y = x)) +
  ggtitle("Some title") +
  theme(plot.title = element_text(lineheight = .8, face = "bold"),
        panel.grid.major = element_blank(),
        panel.grid.minor = element_blank(),
        panel.background = element_blank(),
        panel.margin = unit(c(0, 0, 0, 0), "cm"),
        plot.margin = unit(c(0, 0, 0, 0), "cm"),
        axis.line = element_blank(),
        axis.text.x = element_blank(),
        axis.text.y = element_blank(),
        axis.ticks = element_blank(),
        axis.title.x = element_blank(),
        axis.title.y = element_blank(),
        legend.key = element_rect(linetype = 'blank'))
```

Naturally, the attempt to run this code will not work. In the context of this particular example the error is:

> Error in factor(value) : object 'value' not found

---

## Edit

As requested in the comments below, I have added packages that I use. *By the way of explanation some packages do not have immediate relevance to the code below. I'm using them do do some transformations on the original data, which I use. Just in case, I decided to include the full list. For example package `stringr` should not be relevant here.*

#### Edit 2

It appears that this particular error is concerned with:

```
scale_y_continuous(labels = percent_format()) +
```

when applied to graph definition where multiple data sets are used. Consequently, the final question would be: how can I force the `scale_y...` to use the **original data** and have the remaining plots defined as in the example.

Comment: Could you also add the package(s) you use?

Comment: The current error you have is likely because you set the `fill` globally but there is no `value` variable in your `df_avg` dataset.  Good info on this [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24041190/2461552)

Comment: Thanks, very useful. I was thinking that the problem was with how the `df`'s are added to the `ggplot`. Having said that I reckon that I won't obtain second `y-axis` in `ggplot2` any way.